# pandas convert date to week number

Tags: pandas

I got this error when trying to convert dateto week
Could it be the date values not datetime like values?

```
data['DATECREATED'].dt.week
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxegT.png)

Comment: What is `print(data['DATECREATED'].dtype)` Is it datetime? If not, uncomment row above.

Comment: Hi it is "Object"  ??

Comment: OK, use `data['DATECREATED'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATECREATED'])`

Comment: this work perfect!

Comment: that is good that it works - could you please add data from screenshot as text to your question?

Comment: @rudolf_franek how do I do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert column to `datetime` first and assign back to column:

```
data['DATECREATED'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATECREATED'])
data['new'] = data['DATECREATED'].dt.strftime('%Y%V')
data['CreatedWW'] = data['DATECREATED'].dt.week
```

Comment: got this error: ValueError: time data '26/01/2018' does not match format '%d/%b/%y %H:%M %p' (match)

Answer (score 0):

> Series.dt.weekofyear and Series.dt.week have been deprecated. Please
> call Series.dt.isocalendar() and access the week column instead.

Per the above messaging week of year can no longer be extracted with the above methods. Instead the below should work.

```
data['DATECREATED'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATECREATED'])
data['created_week'] = data['DATECREATED'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

Source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.week.html